# Como deshabilitar la vista de edición de pantalla completa en Landscape?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola quería saber si existe alguna manera de poder eliminar el cuadro blanco que sale encima del teclado cuando introduces texto, en vez de eso que se vea el contenido donde vas a introducirlo.

La cosa es que tengo varias rayas _ _ _ _ _ al estilo ahorcado y al presionar en el primer hueco para introducir la letra el marco blanco me cubre todo y no puedo ver.

Explico en profundidad y añado fotos:
Como quiero que quede
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi que pueda ver exactamente el campo donde escribo.

Como me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sale sin el boton del Search pero es la ventana blanca que os digo y no me deja ver debajo donde estoy escribiendo.

Comment: Me parece que no esta muy clara tu pregunta, podrías colocar alguna imagen de lo que te esta sucediendo para entender un poco mejor el problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa es por la orientación en que tienes la `app`, si la orientación de la pantalla esta en `Landscape` (horizontal) como en tu caso el teclado y el área de escritura por llamarlo de alguna manera se vera así, pero si la orientación de tu `app` es `Portrait` (vertical) esto no pasa, un ejemplo de esto, ve `Whatsapp`, e intenta escribir cualquier mensaje en vertical, que es como normalmente esta, y luego intenta escribir un mensaje con el equipo en horizontal y veras que pasa lo mismo. Esto puedes definirlo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, con la propiedad `android:screenOrientation`="(Portrait o Landscape según necesites en cada actividad o en general de la app)".

Para evitar que se haga un `fullScreen` del `TextView` usa la propiedad `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` en cada `TextView`, ejemplo:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/campo1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"  <------ ASÍ
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero la cosa es que necesito que la posición sea landscape pero sin el marco blanco, como se ve en el ejemplo 1

Comment: Oks, fue fallo mio que no entendí bien la pregunta, actualice mi respuesta, verifica y me dices si te sirvió, saludos

Comment: El android:singleLine="true" está deprecated

Comment: @Webserveis si lo se, solo quería darle un ejemplo, quería que viera donde colocar el flag, ya lo quitaré para que no se confunda nadie mas

Comment: Perfecto jefe me funciona! mis 10!

Answer (score 0):

Se puede conseguir usando el flag `flagNoExtractUi` te dejo la entrada del blog donde hay más información detallada [Android developers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

> El **flagNoExtractUi** elimina completamente el área de texto, permitiendo
>   que la aplicación se vea detrás de ella.

**En XML Layout**

```
<EditText
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" 
.../>
```

**En Java**

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```